# How to create a empty page in JSF app with Netbeans and Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I have a app created by JSF using Primefaces templates in Netbeans.
One of the pages is a Create.xhtml to insert new record in a mysql database. This page is called by a button in a footer of a List od records.
The problem that when I select this page, the form is empty, only have title and buttons. The outputLabel and inputText are "hidden" (inspecting the page in browser). But if I select first a record in the List and next the Create page the outputLabel and inputText already are visible, but with values.
I want that when I select the Create page this came in an empty form and when I want insert the values I wanted in database.
The code of List.xhtml:

```html
<h:form id="DistritoCreateForm">
    <p:panel header="#{bundle.CreateDistritoTitle}">
    <h:panelGroup id="display">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="#{distritoController.selected != null}">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateDistritoLabel_nomeDistrito}" for="nomeDistrito" />
            <p:inputText id="nomeDistrito" value="#{distritoController.selected.nomeDistrito}" title="#{bundle.CreateDistritoTitle_nomeDistrito}" required = "true" />
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{distritoController.create}" value="#{bundle.Save}" update="display,:growl" oncomplete="handleSubmit(args,'DistritoCreateForm');" action="List.xhtml"/>
        <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.Cancel}" action="List.xhtml"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

The code of Create.xhtml:

```html
<h:form id="DistritoListForm">
    <p:panel header="#{bundle.ListDistritoTitle}">
        <p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{distritoController.items}" var="item" style="width:50%;"
                     selectionMode="single" selection="#{distritoController.selected}"
                     paginator="true"
                     paginatorPosition="bottom"
                     rowKey="#{item.id}"
                     rows="10">

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"   update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>

            <p:column filterBy="#{item.nomeDistrito}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDistritoTitle_nomeDistrito}"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.nomeDistrito}"/>
            </p:column>
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton id="createButton" icon="ui-icon-plus" actionListener="#{distritoController.prepareCreate}" action="Create.xhtml"/>
                <p:commandButton id="viewButton"   icon="ui-icon-search" action="View.xhtml"/>
                <p:commandButton id="editButton"   icon="ui-icon-pencil" action="Edit.xhtml"/>
                <p:commandButton id="deleteButton" icon="ui-icon-trash" actionListener="#{distritoController.destroy}" update=":growl,datalist" disabled="#{empty distritoController.selected}"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So effectively (it cannot be seen in your code since it is not an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

- You select something
- As a consequence a certain variable is set to be used in the shared 'show'/'edit'/'create' page/dialog
- Next you press the create button and the same page/dialog is shown with the content from the selection before.

A simple deduction then is that the 'selected' variable is not cleared in the method that is called when the create button is pressed (`#{distritoController.prepareCreate}`)

**Solution:**

Clear the variable (e.g. by creating a new empty instance of the object...

Effectively this is not a PrimeFaces problem (same would happen with plain jsf too) and it sort of is not a 'java' problem either but a plain coding issue.